# Core Data, KVO, and NSInternalInconsistencyException

Tags: iphone, cocoa, core-data, key-value-observing, cocoa-design-patterns

I'm using Core Data and KVO to look for changes in values to trigger saves to the data store. I have a table view with search hooked up to `NSFetchedResultsController`. When the search changes, a new results controller is made on pressing the Search button. When the user selects an item in the results table view, then the user enters a detail view and can make edits.

This is where I encounter the problems. When the user makes a change in a separate UIControl that I made, the detail view is notified and can use the `NSFetchedResultsController` it remembers from when the table view pushed me onto the view stack to get the `NSManagedObjectContext` and do a save. When I do so, I sometimes get the following error:

```
Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  no object at index 89 in section at index 0 with userInfo (null)
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'no object at index 89 in section at index 0'
```

I found that this tends to happen when I do a search and an object that isn't on the top of the table is moved up to the top. I vaguely know what might be wrong in the back of my head, but would appreciate any pointers as to how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong. I forgot to unset the old `NSFetchedResultsController`'s delegate, and also forgot to release said `NSFetchedResultsController`. My `UITableView` subclass also responded to updates to the `NSFetchedResultsController` through delegates, and caused weird calls to be made.

Comment: Glad to see you solved the issue.  That issue is pretty common and easy to forget :)